# Web3js - Return smart contract address immediately after deployment

Tags: javascript, blockchain, smartcontracts, web3js

I have a smart contract which I am deploying using the Web3.js package. I have a function called `deploySmartContract()` which does so, and I am expecting this method to return contract address to the calling function. Below is the snippet for `deploySmartContract()` -

```
function deploySmartContract(shareName, symbol, maxSupply) {
    var _shareName = shareName;
    var _symbol = symbol;
    var _maxSupply = maxSupply;
    var contractAddr = '';

    var sharesregistry = contractObj.new(
        _shareName,
        _symbol,
        _maxSupply,
        {
            from: primaryAccount, 
            data: byteCode, 
            gas: '5000000'
        }, function (e, contract){
            console.log(e, contract);
            if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
                console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
            }
        }
    );
    console.log(sharesregistry.address);

    return sharesregistry;
}
```

How can I keep my return statement waiting unless the whole transaction is completed and execute return when contract is mined? Else I am getting just an skeleton of `shareregistry` object at the calling function.

Here, I confirm that this code deploys the smart contract perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout [API new](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract) method and how to call it synchronously and asynchronously. You have provided callback functions which means you run it asynchronously. By removing it, you force it to wait for a result.